# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException even when path of driver is set

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am getting below exception when I am running a selenium browser initialization using java main method. The driver is available at the right path.

> The path to the driver executable must be set by the
>   webdriver.chrome.driver system property;   for more information, see
>   https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. The latest
>   version can be downloaded from
>   http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html     at
>   com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:738)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:124)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.access$000(ChromeDriverService.java:32)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(ChromeDriverService.java:137)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:330)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:88)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:124)
>     at
>   invokebrowser.myfirsttestcase.initBroiwser(myfirsttestcase.java:23)
>     at invokebrowser.myfirsttestcase.main(myfirsttestcase.java:16)

**Code Snippet**

```
System.setProperty("Webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Javalibs\\chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();//getting exception here
```

Comment: Please format your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code, Webdriver.code.driver..., W is mentioned in capital letter. It has to be in small letter as shown in the error message.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Javalibs\\chromedriver.exe");
```

Hope this helps you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

While you work with Selenium 3.4.0, chromedriver 2.29 & Chrome 58.x you have to specify the absolute path of the chromedriver through `System.setProperty`

It's worth mentioning that the System Property is **webdriver.chrome.driver**

While you mention the absolute path of the chromedriver through `System.setProperty`, you have to either provide front slashes "**/**" or escape the back slashes "**\\**"

Your own code block will work for you with this simple twist:

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Javalibs\\chromedriver.exe"); 
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

> OR

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:/Javalibs/chromedriver.exe"); 
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.